# Identity Server 4 Consent Screen Never Shows

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm trying to get the Consent Screen to show from the [Identity Server 4 Samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples),
I've configured the client so it requires consent like so:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "openIdConnectClient",
    ClientName = "Example Implicit Client Application",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    RequireConsent = true,
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
        "role",
        "customAPI"
     },
     RedirectUris = new List<string> {"https://localhost:44330/signin-oidc"},
     PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> { "https://localhost:44330" }
 }
```

The project contains controllers and views for the Consent Screen However I cannot get it to load. If needed I can show the classes or views for the Consent.

Does anyone know how to configure IdentityServer4 to Display the Consent Screen?

Comment: I assume that the sign in process does actually work, you just don't get consent displayed as part of the process? Could you perhaps provide the Identity Server logs generated during the sign in process?

Comment: Have you configured the consent URL for IDS when you setup IDS for your DI container? is there a controller responsible for that url?

Comment: There is a controller responsible but I don't see it referenced anywhere. I'm not exactly sure where it should be

Comment: Are you using a persistent store? Consent decision might be stored already.

Comment: Did you try to put the debug point in the index action of ConsentController ?

Comment: MJK, The Consent Controller is never hit, I also don't see it referenced anywhere

Comment: @leastprivilege, Im using stores for users, how could I clear out a consent decision if it is already stored?

Comment: If you are not using our operational stores. Try recycling the app. Compare with your our QuickStarts.

Comment: HAving the same problem here. Have you been able to resolve yours?

Comment: I think I was using the wrong flow complete. I ending up switching to the JS API Example, and everything was working fine.  I think I had offline consent on so the screen never appeared again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force the consent screen to always be shown in your client by setting the Prompt property when you register the OpenIDConnect scheme:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:6001";
            options.ClientId = "xxx";
            options.ClientSecret = "xxxx";
            options.ResponseType = "code";
       
            ...

            options.Prompt = "consent";
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Identity Server is remembering your previous consent. Just add this to the client options (the default value is `true`):

```cs
    AllowRememberConsent = false,
```